# xsl-fo fo:table-row page-break after specific row number PDF creation

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

```
<fo:table-body>
 <xsl:for-each select="dummy">
  <xsl:variable name="r" select="position()"/>

   <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
     <fo:block>
       some text
     </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
   </fo:table-row>

 </xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-body>
```

So this is my Code. What I want to do is to break the page after a specific number of rows (17 in my case) and continue on the next page.

What I tried so far:

```
<fo:table-body>
     <xsl:for-each select="dummy">
      <xsl:variable name="r" select="position()"/>

       <fo:table-row>

        <xsl:if test="$r mod 17 = 0">
         <xsl:attribute name="break-after">page</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <fo:table-cell>
         <fo:block>
         </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
       </fo:table-row> 

</fo:table-body>
```

This adds the attribute to the row.
However when the fo is then used to create a PDF the page-break does not happen.

I am using Altsoft XML2PDF Converter. But I think the problem is in the xslt.

Comment: You attempt should be correct especially given the answer below except it has to be tested on altsoft. It works for other formatters I tested. You can report a bug to them and also try other tricks like moving the break into a block in the table itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fo:table-row/@page-break-after is not defined in XSL 1.1. Probably you can modify this attribute as follwoing if XML2PDF conforms XSL 1.1:

```
<xsl:if test="$r mod 17 = 0">
    <xsl:attribute name="break-after">page</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

See applicable fo:table-row attribute from the following URL:

[6.7.9 fo:table-row](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_table-row)

According to your comment I've tested using simple example.

[Input XML]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <dummy>A</dummy>
    <dummy>B</dummy>
    <dummy>C</dummy>
    ...
    <dummy>P</dummy>
    <dummy>Q</dummy>
    <dummy>R</dummy>
    ...
    <dummy>X</dummy>
    <dummy>Y</dummy>
    <dummy>Z</dummy>
</root>
```

[Stylesheet]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="spm" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin="10mm 10mm 10mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <xsl:for-each select="dummy">
                                <xsl:variable name="r" select="position()"/>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <xsl:if test="$r mod 17 = 0">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="break-after">page</xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Result FO (excerpt)]

```
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>P</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row break-after="page">
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>Q</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>R</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

[Formatting result]

[image: Formatting result]

Comment: I already did try this one. Sadly no change. I believe the Problem is with the dynamic creation of the rows. The "break-after" Attribute only works if there is another object after the row. But somehow the next row is not recognized as an object.

Comment: I also did edit my question to the correct Attribute. Thanks for that ;)

Comment: Okay so it must either be Altsoft or something else in my XSLT.. I will have another look. Thank you!